# Liferay: After changing Public Virtual Host settings, can't log in

Tags: virtual, liferay, host

I did a mistake and seems like I can't fix it alone, if it can be fixed. I have the Liferay URL looking like this: `http://192.168.10.10:8080/web/guest`; I wanted to remove the `'/web/guest'` part from the address so from Manage -> Settings wrote `192.168.10.10:8080` to the Public Virtual Host field. After saving it, I can't log in anymore. Everytime I write `http://192.168.10.10:8080/login` (as I did before), it goes to the index page and not the login page.

Then if I write the `login` after `'web/guest'`, I can go to the login page, but when I fill in the Username and Password field and hit Submit button, it goes nowhere, that is no action taken, which most probably is because of the permissions that I have set earlier. Only owner has full rights.

I thought somewhere in the database (MySql) I could clear what I have written to the Public Virtual Host field, but from the table names couldn't tell which table is for that. Now I am trying to change the user privileges from the DB, no result yet. I even restored the DB from a 2-weeks-old dump, but seems like the Public Virtual Host changes are saved somewhere else and not the DB.

I appreciate any help or insight on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What Liferay version du you use?

Comment: I am using Liferay 6.0.6. Ah, I looked at the source code of the index page and I noticed that the default URL http://192.168.10.10:8080 is changed to http://192.168.10.10:8080:8080, which could be the source of the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally solved the problem. I just needed to fix the virtual host from the database.

Here is my script in case someone did what I did:)

```
update LayoutSet SET
    -> virtualHost = '192.168.10.10'
    -> WHERE virtualHost = '192.168.10.10:8080';
```