# Liferay blog URL's and virtual host

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, utf-8, liferay

Our company running Liferay without virtual host. We using VM IP with port 80 open for our portal. No any problems with this setup.

When I'm added virtual host to Liferay and changed DNS on my machine -- I can't opened any assets (articles) with long russian names.

Tomcat console:

```
WARN  [404_jsp:109] /home/-/asset_publisher/JbL5ejmhvwSa/content/%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-ibm
```

Virtual host enabled URL (not working)

```
http://companyname.com/home/-/asset_publisher/JbL5ejmhvwSa/content/%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-ibm?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Finterprocom.ru%2Fhome%3Fp_p_id%3D101_INSTANCE_JbL5ejmhvwSa%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dnormal%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26p_p_col_id%3Dcolumn-2%26p_p_col_pos%3D1%26p_p_col_count%3D2
```

Virtual host disabled URL (working)

```
http://192.168.10.35/web/guest/home/-/asset_publisher/JbL5ejmhvwSa/content/%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-ibm?redirect=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.10.45%2Fweb%2Fguest%2Fhome%3Fp_p_id%3D101_INSTANCE_JbL5ejmhvwSa%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dnormal%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26p_p_col_id%3Dcolumn-2%26p_p_col_pos%3D1%26p_p_col_count%3D2
```

It's few days until we go public. We'll use our domain companyname.com

I'm worried that we will got same issue.

Comment: How exactly did you configure virtual host? You should configure it for "instance".

Comment: Hi Is any update on this issue as I am also facing the same.
Please reply as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to immediately solve the underlying problem: You can also use the last option with the host name: No virtual host names, just have the name resolve to 192.168.10.35 (change to an actual IP when going live).

Also, what version of Liferay are you on?

Comment: Liferay 6.1.0 CE. Tomcat 7.0.23. We want beautiful and short URL's. IP address adding web/guest to URL. No way.

Answer (score 0):

see this Question, my be it help you: [Liferay: After changing Public Virtual Host settings, can't log in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794144/liferay-after-changing-public-virtual-host-settings-cant-log-in)

Also you can see in generated jsp code `tomcat/work/...`  why this do not work.
And at last, you can debug Liferay and find the solution :) The simple way to debug Liferay is to get Liferay IDE and add Liferay Source as eclipse project. Good luck.

Comment: I already tried solution from your question. I cant find virtualHost column (or row) in my DB.

Comment: And by the way -- thank you for answer. I did not find a lot .jsp's under `tomcat/work/...` -- just empty folders named same as portlets.Found one .jsp in open-social-portlet but it's no use here.

Comment: look for something like `jsp_file_name`_jsp.java

Answer (score 0):

Even I face this issue and observed that with liferay's virtual host mapping, url's with special characters are not showing up when they are related to entries in Guest site.

> By mapping virtual host, web/guest part is removed from the URL.

Now if you try manually adding web/guest before the URL, In your case

try accessing with following URL

http://companyname.com/web/guest/home/-/asset_publisher/JbL5ejmhvwSa/content/%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-ibm?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Finterprocom.ru%2Fhome%3Fp_p_id%3D101_INSTANCE_JbL5ejmhvwSa%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dnormal%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26p_p_col_id%3Dcolumn-2%26p_p_col_pos%3D1%26p_p_col_count%3D2

and it should work.

> So one possible way to resolve this issue is to keep virtual host
>   mapping in your windows/your os hosts file and rename virtual host to
>   localhost in Liferay in portal settings under Portal tab in control
>   panel.

STEPS:

```
1) In hosts file keep the mapping as you have done i.e 
   192.168.10.35           companyname.com

2) In liferay, remove the virtual host mapping i.e rename virtual host to localhost in "portal settings" under "Portal" tab in control panel.

and try to access your entry and it will work.
```

This is very interesting behavior/ may be a bug in liferay.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a liferay bug and we created ticket for this and got fix from liferay.

Answer (score -1):

So you testing Liferay on your local host, then trying to move on real domain and facing some weird behaviour.

First thing you want to do is to check Control Panel and type in your new virtual host there.

[image]

I'm not sure about this because we are using 6.0 now and I did not remember how exactly we fixed it. If my advice did not helped please check other comments to this question.

Comment: This seems to be a liferay bug as we have tested it on clean bundle and observer that for public pages of Guest site with virtual mapping defined causes url's with special characters to redirect to home page or previously open link in portal. 
We have open a ticket regarding the same.
will update once get reply from Liferay.